# pipenv giving errors "ImportError" and "OSError"

Tags: python, virtualenv, importerror

```
$ pipenv --two
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Running virtualenv with interpreter /mnt/ilustre/users/miniconda2/bin/python2
New python executable in /mnt/ilustre/users/.local/share/virtualenvs/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /mnt/ilustre/users/.local/share/virtualenvs/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /mnt/ilustre/users/s...s_report/bin/python2 - setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/mnt/ilustre/users/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/mnt/ilustre/users/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
```

### ImportError: /mnt/ilustre/users/.local/share/virtualenvs/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_Concat

```
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/ilustre/users/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2328, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/ilustre/users/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/mnt/ilustre/users/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/mnt/ilustre/users/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/mnt/ilustre/users/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /mnt/ilustre/users/s...s_report/bin/python2 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1

Virtualenv location:
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this question. The reason is the python version used by virtualenv. You can run 'which virtualenv' and then edit the virtualenv file which is a python file. You must change the python interpreter. I change to the 2.7.10 version and virtualenv runs okay. It is 2.7.11 version previously so it reports errors!